# How to implement ComponentDidCatch in SPFx

Tags: spfx, reactjs

Could someone please show me how to implement ComponentDidCatch in SPFx. I did it successfully in ReactJs like this: Throwing an Error :

```
throw new Error('I crashed!');
```

and it would get caught here:

```
componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
      // Catch errors in any components below and re-render with error message
      this.setState({
        error: error,
        errorInfo: errorInfo
      })
      // You can also log error messages to an error reporting service here
    }
```

However, when I tried to do the same for SPFx , I would get the below error in the browser console, while throwing the error:

**Uncaught (in promise) Error: I crashed**

Is there a way to catch this error in SPFx?

Comment: Where are you writing this method in your webpart? Check how to use it in react at: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html